# Cache Simulator :: Hit vs Miss issue

Tags: c, caching, simulator

For Cache that is: 1MB size, 4-way set assoc and 32B per block.
Memory size 16MB (so phy_address is 24 bits)
(Refer to:  http://people.duke.edu/~tkb13/courses/ece250-2018su/homeworks/homework5.pdf - page 6)

Trace:

`store 0xd53170 4 7d2f13ac *// instr phys_addr access_size data`*

`load 0xd53172 1 *// instr phys_add access_size`*

I wrote a c-program that executed the following as:

`./cachesim traces/example.txt 1024 4 32`

Output:

`store 0xd53170 miss`

`load 0xd53172 hit 13`

Issue or question is hit on 2nd load. Expected output is miss. However, my program sees it as a hit. My programs sees miss in previous line. Fills in cache and then marks that block as valid. Thus leading to a hit on load.
I get my:

`tag=0x35, set=0x98b, offset=0x10 (and 0x12 for load)`

Let me know if you can answer why 2nd line is miss vs hit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The document states that
"The cache is write-through and write-no-allocate."

This means that on a write miss, nothing will happen in the cache. Data will be written in the main memory, but no allocation takes place in the cache.

store 0xd53170 miss (forward to memory, allocate nothing in the cache)

load 0xd53172 miss (line not allocated in the cache, so this IS a miss)

Probably you do no manage properly in your simulator write misses.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I am writing up the code as follows now.  `if(cache->set[set_].block[i].tag == tag_ && cache->set[set_].block[i].valid == 1 && (!(strcmp(loadStore, "store")==0)))  -> hit`